# Grid SelectionMode.MULTI is missing the header checkbox to select all for BackEndDataProvider

Tags: vaadin-grid, vaadin8

I am working with a new application written to version 8 (currently testing with 8.1.0.rc2).

The issue surrounds the "select all" checkbox that appears in the header of a `Grid` when using `SelectionMode.MULTI`. In particular, the problem is that the checkbox appears and operates as expected when the `DataProvider` implements `InMemoryDataProvider`, but the checkbox does not appear when the `DataProvider` implements `BackEndDataProvider`.

The following code creates two grids that differ only in whether they use InMemory or BackEnd:

```
public class Test {
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    private String name;
}

public class TestView extends BaseView {
    public TestView() {
        super("Test");
        addComponent(new TestGrid(new TestDataProvider0()));
        addComponent(new TestGrid(new TestDataProvider1()));
    }
}

public class TestGrid extends Grid<Test> {
    public TestGrid(DataProvider<Test, ?> dataProvider) {
        setHeightByRows(4);
        setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);
        setDataProvider(dataProvider);
        addColumn(Test::getName).setCaption("Name");
    }
}

public class TestDataProvider0 extends AbstractDataProvider<Test, SerializablePredicate<Test>> implements
        BackEndDataProvider<Test, SerializablePredicate<Test>> {
    public Stream<Test> fetch(Query<Test, SerializablePredicate<Test>> query) {
        List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>(query.getLimit());
        for (int i = 0; i < query.getLimit(); i++) {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.setName(String.valueOf(query.getOffset() + i));
            tests.add(test);
        }
        return tests.stream();
    }
    public int size(Query<Test, SerializablePredicate<Test>> query) {
        return 100;
    }
    public void setSortOrders(List<QuerySortOrder> sortOrders) {
    }
}

public class TestDataProvider1 extends AbstractDataProvider<Test, SerializablePredicate<Test>> implements
        InMemoryDataProvider<Test> {
    public Stream<Test> fetch(Query<Test, SerializablePredicate<Test>> query) {
        List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>(query.getLimit());
        for (int i = 0; i < query.getLimit(); i++) {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.setName(String.valueOf(query.getOffset() + i));
            tests.add(test);
        }
        return tests.stream();
    }
    public int size(Query<Test, SerializablePredicate<Test>> query) {
        return 100;
    }
    public SerializablePredicate<Test> getFilter() {
        return null;
    }
    public void setFilter(SerializablePredicate<Test> filter) {
    }
    public SerializableComparator<Test> getSortComparator() {
        return null;
    }
    public void setSortComparator(SerializableComparator<Test> comparator) {
    }
}
```

Here is how the grids are rendered:
[image: Screenshot]

Have I missed a critical step in setting up my BackEnd-based data provider/grid? The [related documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-providers.html#datamodel.dataproviders) does not seem to address this issue.

Is there a known issue related to this?

Is select-all not available by design? Obviously, this could interact really badly with the concept of lazy-loading on a large data set...

Comment: I made a quick sample, no filters, nothing fancy, using `DataProvider.ofCollection(people)` and it behaves normally. Can you please share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @Morfic I appreciate you taking a look and indicating that this should work. I will start ripping stuff out of the code to see where the problem is.

Comment: @Morfic Question has been rewritten based on further investigation. It looks like it works with a DataProvider that implements InMemoryDataProvider, but does not work when BackEndDataProvider is implemented instead. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MultiSelectionModelImpl has this method:

```
protected void updateCanSelectAll() {
    switch (selectAllCheckBoxVisibility) {
    case VISIBLE:
        getState(false).selectAllCheckBoxVisible = true;
        break;
    case HIDDEN:
        getState(false).selectAllCheckBoxVisible = false;
        break;
    case DEFAULT:
        getState(false).selectAllCheckBoxVisible = getGrid()
                .getDataProvider().isInMemory();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

This indicates that the default behavior for non-in-memory providers is to not show the select-all checkbox, but that this behavior can be overridden by setting the visibility to `VISIBLE`.

Tweaking the original code here:

```
public class TestGrid extends Grid<Test> {
    public TestGrid(DataProvider<Test, ?> dataProvider) {
        setHeightByRows(4);
        MultiSelectionModel<Test> selectionModel = (MultiSelectionModel<Test>) setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);
        selectionModel.setSelectAllCheckBoxVisibility(SelectAllCheckBoxVisibility.VISIBLE);
        setDataProvider(dataProvider);
        addColumn(Test::getName).setCaption("Name");
    }
}
```

Specifically, this call is required for the checkbox to appear for data providers that implement BackEndDataProvider:

```
MultiSelectionModel<Test> selectionModel = (MultiSelectionModel<Test>) setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);
selectionModel.setSelectAllCheckBoxVisibility(SelectAllCheckBoxVisibility.VISIBLE);
```

With this change, the select-all checkbox now appears:
[image: Fixed screenshot]